# Перфоманс метода getOne()

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-jpa, spring-data-jpa

Имеется сущность `Menu`. Она выглядит примерно так:

```
// аннотации опущены
public class Menu {
    Integer id;
    Restaurant restaurant;
    List<Dish> dishes;
    LocalDate date;
}
```

Я хочу сделать для неё DTO, в котором вместо поля `Restaurant restaurant` будет `Integer restaurantId`, а вместо `List<Dish> dishes` будет `List<Integer> dishIds`. Но если я захочу переобразовать это DTO в реальный объект `Menu` *(чтобы потом сохранить в DataJpa-репозиторий например, потому что DataJpa работает с реальными объектами)*, мне надо как-то вытащить все эти сущности по id.

Я предполагаю использовать для этого метод `getOne()` из JpaRepository. Однако меня волнует перфоманс этого метода. Он вообще обращается к БД? Насколько он дорог в использовании?

Answer (score 1):

> Он вообще обращается к БД?

Не могу гарантировать, но исходя из общих соображений, думаю, что должен. Ведь, что значит "не обращаться в БД"? Это значит хранить кеш всей базы в оперативной памяти и грамотно управлять актуальностью его состояния. Я не верю в такой функционал по-дефолту. Такое вы только сами себе запилить можете.

> использовать для этого метод getOne() из JpaRepository. Однако меня волнует перфоманс этого метода.

Если в базе всё стандартно и айдишник (как и положено) является первичным ключом, то ни о каких проблемах перфоманса, ИМХО, речи быть не может.

Нет, понятно, что если база и джава на разных машинах и время тратится на сеть и всё такое. Но в любом случае это обычная нагрузка. Если у нас не супер нагруженное приложение и мы не кешируем руками базу или её часть в оперативке, то ходить в базу мы не боимся. Поход в базу может оказаться дорогостоящим потому, что запрос криво составлен. Но к поиску по айди это отношения не имеет.

Comment: Я нашёл вот это: _Метод EntityManager.getReference возвращает прокси-сервер Hibernate без запроса базы данных и установки свойств вашей сущности. Метод JpaRepository.getOne использует метод EntityManager.getReference вместо метода EntityManager.find . поэтому всякий раз, когда вам нужен управляемый объект, но вам не нужно запрашивать базу данных для этого, лучше использовать метод JpaRepostory.getOne , чтобы устранить ненужный запрос._

https://coderoad.ru/33218762/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-CrudRepository-findOne-%D0%B8-JpaRepository-getOne

Comment: Не, ок, я ни в коем случае не возражаю. Если хибернейт таки чо-то кешриует, то флаг ему в руки. От себя могу только ещё раз повторить, мы в коммерческой разработке ходить в базу в принципе не боимся. Конечно, бывают разные приложения, но,блин, заморачиваться с вопросом, долго ли искать по первичному ключу, ИМХО, не стоит. Если вам очень принципиальна скорость доступа к какой-то таблице, ну, закешируйте её руками. То есть храние её данные в модельках в оперативе и постоянно синхронизируйте обновления между моделями и базой. Но сомневаюсь, что это действительно нужно.

Comment: Ну если операция выполняется часто, то не хотелось бы дёргать базу лишний раз. Но, похоже, getOne() её и не дёргает.